# Python Pandas DF computing new column (mean for groups)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to compute two new columns in a dataframe. I have two variables gender and income and I need two new columns female_average_income and male_average_income for the same df. I found several ways by grouping and aggregating but thats not hat I need. just two plain columns in the same df. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

A simple method would be just to use two `loc` calls and filter on gender:

```
In [390]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':['m','f','m','m','f'], 'income':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[390]:
  gender    income
0      m -0.960345
1      f  0.876803
2      m -0.328706
3      m -0.826363
4      f  0.763037
In [391]:

df.loc[df.gender=='f', 'female_avg_income'], df.loc[df.gender=='m','male_avg_income'] = df.loc[df.gender=='f']['income'].mean(), df.loc[df.gender=='m']['income'].mean()
df
Out[391]:
  gender    income  female_avg_income  male_avg_income
0      m -0.960345                NaN        -0.705138
1      f  0.876803            0.81992              NaN
2      m -0.328706                NaN        -0.705138
3      m -0.826363                NaN        -0.705138
4      f  0.763037            0.81992              NaN
```

A better way would be to use `transform` on the groupby object which will align the returned data:

```
In [392]:

df.loc[df.gender=='f', 'female_avg_income'], df.loc[df.gender=='m','male_avg_income'] = df.groupby('gender')['income'].transform(np.mean), df.groupby('gender')['income'].transform(np.mean)
df
Out[392]:
  gender    income  female_avg_income  male_avg_income
0      m -0.960345                NaN        -0.705138
1      f  0.876803            0.81992              NaN
2      m -0.328706                NaN        -0.705138
3      m -0.826363                NaN        -0.705138
4      f  0.763037            0.81992              NaN
```

Comment: thank you. would it be possible to have female_avg_income  in every row? Eventhough it wouldn't made sense at the first glance?

Comment: You could do so by doing this `df['female_avg_income'] = df['female_avg_income'].fillna(mehot='backfill')`, also if my answer helped you then you can accept it, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of my answer